# Stack Exchange password on my Gmail address. Both accounts are there on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

I created my account on Stack Overflow using Stack Exchange and my previous company's email Id. After joining my new company I forgot my password on Stack Exchange. I was no longer able to regain my password since the email id provided was of the previous company (which I cannot access now).

Somehow when I opened Stack Overflow I was already logged in. Now I added more logins (to my account) and provided my Gmail account. Now I want to get my Stack Exchange password on my Gmail account. Is it possible?

Comment: Use [this form](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other) please and the team will handle this. There is no automated process.